# Shifting rows of data by removing last row to accept new row data in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a requirement where my application is receiving some telemetry data regularly from another application in json format example:

```
{
  "blvel":12,
  "load":1,
  "pres":201
}
```

This I intend to retain only latest 100 records based on timestamp like below in my application

```
timestamp      | blvel | load | pres
1-1-2000 0:0:0 |   12  | 1    | 201
1-1-2000 0:1:0 |   11  | 0    | 12
```

When I receive 101 record, I should discard the oldest timestamp record from my list and insert the 101 record, so that i will always have the latest 100 records.

How can I achieve this in python?
Is it possible to do using pandas?

I did not find any ready to use library for this. If any please share.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please provide code that reproduces the exact objects that you have. You don't show JSON but a dictionary, also you only show data for one new row, do you receive it one by one or by group? It looks you just need to create a new dataframe from the data, then `concat`  this and the last 100-N rows of the previous dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use deque module from  collections package

1. Declare the maxlength of your queue
2. Append to the queue , and the first element is automatically discarded and new element is added at the end.

> ```
> from collections import deque
> max_length=100
> #declaring a queue
> queue = deque([None]*max_length,max_length)
> queue.append("A") #call this function whenever u want to add a new data
> ```